# Trouble with prompting the user for input until it is correct in a while loop

Tags: python, factorial

```
if num < 0:
    input('Only  nonnegative intergervalues allowed, try again: ')
elif num == 0:
    print('The factorial of 0 = 1')

while num > 1:
    factor = factor * num
    num = num -1
else:
    num = int(input('Only  nonnegative intergervalues allowed, try again: '))
```

This is what I have. I'm only trying to use the while loop for the program. It prompts the user twice if the integer is negative and then the loop breaks. I need the loop to keep prompting the user until correct input is given. I'm not sure where the error is. Do I need a nested while loop or is the problem with the else statement?

I've tried another while loop underneath the original loop but unsure if I had it done correctly. Also tried moving some things around?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue is with your interpretation of the `else` on the `while` loop. It will only ever get executed once, as the while loops exits without a `break`. I think your expectation was that after the else block, the while condition would be evaluated again. This is not the case, use an `if` statement in the while loop instead.

You probably wanted something like:

```
# since Python does not have a repeat .. until loop, while True with a break works
while True:
    num = int(input('Enter a non-negative integer value: '))
    if num < 0:
        input('Only non-negative integer values allowed, try again: ')
    else:
        break

factorial = 1
x = num  # save num to print later, work with x to compute factorial

while x > 0:
    factorial = factorial * x
    x = x - 1

print(f'The factorial of {num} is: {factorial}')
```

The `else` on a `while` loop can be useful, if you need to do something only if the loop completes without a break. For example:

```
total = 0
while total <= 10:
    s = input(f'Total is {total}, add how much? ("x" to stop): ')
    if s == 'x':
        break
    total = total + int(s)
else:
    print(f'You reached a total over 10 of {total}')
```

A few notes on your code:

- the first part reads text input into `num`, but doesn't do anything with it. You probably left some of your code out, as `num` isn't defined before the `if` statement.
- the second part assumes `num` has an `int` value, because that's what it compares it with, but at that point the value would be a `str`.
- the `else` part of the `while` would *always* execute if `num` were a positive integer, but that's not the behaviour you want - however, if `num` were negative, it would never be reached, since that's not what the `else` on a `while` is for.

On a personal note, I don't like the fact that the `else` keyword was reused on `for` and `while` in Python. Something like `after` would have made more sense. But programming languages like to keep the number of keywords to a minimum, and `else` was reused here, leading to the confusion you had - which makes sense when first learning the language.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried the while true: loop in your answer. It gives me a repeat of input until a positive integer is given. One issue I'm having now is that when an initial positive integer is given it prompts the user the error message. When given the same positive integer it produces the expected outcome. Could it be that I have my variables in the wrong places to cause this error?

Comment: When I run the code in my answer, it does not behave like you describe. I think you adapted your code with something from my answer, and there is still a remaining issue with your solution? It may seem silly to ask a very similar question again, but you could consider posting a new question (and even refer to this one as background), asking about a remaining issue you have with the code. It's possible there's some other oversight that I didn't address or explain properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
# The external loop if input is invalid
i = 0
while i < 5:
    
    # If it is 5th attempt, error message
    if i == 4:
        print('Sorry, The maximum number of attempts exceeded')
    
    #Upto 5 times of invalid input, takes another input
    num = int(input())

    #If the input is valid
    if num > 0:
        r = 1
        while num >= 1:
            r = r * num
            num = num - 1
        print(r)
        break    
    else :
        print('The number can not be zero or negative')
    i += 1
```